# Debug which Javascript is causing a redirect

Tags: javascript

We have mountains of Javascript. Somewhere in there, a redirect is happening that we don't want. How can you generically debug which code caused a redirect? A stack trace would be perfect.

Comment: you can use a packet sniffer such as fiddler2 to detect the redirect, and then step through your code line by line while watching for the redirect.

Answer (score 3):

Another person asked a similar question. Someone gave a helpful option in chrome debugging tools that you could try out. See link below.

[Break javascript before an inline javascript redirect in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360187/break-javascript-before-an-inline-javascript-redirect-in-chrome#answer-12419326)

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy way. You could do a mass search in your files for some words like "redirect", "window.location", "location" and the like.