# How to find where javascript is redirecting to another page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug an issue on complex javascript page in Chrome, where ultimately clicking on a link ends up redirecting to another page.

I'd like to find out where the code is that's actually doing the redirect, but can't seem to spot it.

I can see in the `Network` tab of DevTools that the `Initiator` was a certain bit of javascript, but when I click on that link and view the javascript, I don't see any `window.location...` references of any sort, and have tried debugging through the code, but can't find it.

**Is there an easy way to detect when `window.location` is being used to redirect the page, even if it's being used in some wrapper library?**

EDIT: Note - I've tried setting a breakpoint for the `window.unload` event, [as detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12360187/26510), but no luck.

Comment: try listening to click handler via dev tools and see which code executes when

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360187/break-javascript-before-an-inline-javascript-redirect-in-chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you, I have had this issue before:

1. `Open Developer Tools`
2. `Go to Sources tab`
3. `Look for Event Listener Breakpoints`
4. `Expand Load option`
5. `Here check unload option`

Hope it helps! :)